# How to handle app icon badge count when app receives notification in background(closed) on react-native using expo? (IOS)

Tags: ios, react-native, push-notification, expo

Is there a possible way to auto increment app icon badge number for iOS when app receives a push notification?
I mean by just calling Notifications.setBadgeNumberAsync while app is in background or hasn't launched yet?

Expo sdk version: 33.0.0
https://docs.expo.io/versions/v33.0.0/workflow/upgrading-expo-sdk-walkthrough/#sdk-33